# Scan Image directory and create Json object

Tags: json, angular, image, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to scan a directory of images obtained through a URL and create a Json object from that directory. The purpose of this is so that I can reference and bind this object in my Ionic project. I tried to find solutions to this. However, I cannot find any. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**edit**
I realized that my question was not too clear. What I am asking is how I can convert a directory of URL into base64.

Comment: If you are getting the data from url in a json format then you can simply assign it to a global variable and use inside your app to bind to html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with a solution. I have used the tree command which will generate a json file from a directory. Afterwards, I used a py script to join this json file into my main json file.

`tree --dirsfirst --noreport -n -J -i -s -D --dirsfirst -f -o my.json`

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="terms"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let c of weapons?.weapon_category?.weapons | search : terms">
      <button  ion-item (click)="presentPopover($event,c)">
           <img width="80" height="80" src="/assets/weapon/{{c.image}}"/>
           <h2>{{c.name}}</h2>
      </button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```